# Find Script start time and uptime in centos

Tags: linux, centos, php, cpu-usage

I have a php script (cron job) running on my server which takes up a lot of cpu. I took a look on the code and couldn't find anything wrong. Now I have to check the logs for anomaly and for this I need to get the script start time and/or uptime. I tried top, ps -aux, htop etc but couldn't get that. Is there any other command/method available for this?

`ps -aux | grep php` shows Oct 11, the date. But How can I get the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run

```
ps -o lstart PID
```

Which will give the start time of the process.

Comment: Thank you Matthew. However, there is a syntax error in your answer. There should be a comma between lstart and PID.

Comment: No there shouldn't, your supposed to put the pid you want in PID. If you want the start time of EVERY Process then you would do `ps -Ao lstart,pid`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest wrapping the php script inside a shell script:

`date >/your/log ; /usr/bin/time /path/to/your.php`

Answer (score 0):

If you know PID of script; you can get the start time of script with

> stat  -c %z /proc/PID

Additionally you can analyze what's going on in script with `strace` e.g.

> strace -p PID -s 128 -tT

This will give you idea where time is spent in this process which appears to be trashing your CPU

Comment: stat -c %z will show the Time of last change right? I need to get the time at which the script started or the script uptime so that I can match it with my log and find the issue. And strace is giving me just a blank output and stat -c %z is giving me the current date.

Comment: that is the time directory of process was created; time is never altered throughout the process lifetime; make sure that you put PID of process instead PID